# AWS Amplify build failed non-zero exit code detected

Tags: reactjs, deployment, build, aws-amplify

My React app has always built without a problem with AWS Amplify until recently where it keeps failing. I have tried every solution I could find online to no avail. Would anybody know a fix to this? Here is the error log:

```
2023-01-03T15:16:12.248Z [INFO]: # Cloning repository: git@github.com:othmanez314/inket.git
2023-01-03T15:16:13.956Z [INFO]: 
2023-01-03T15:16:13.959Z [INFO]: Cloning into 'inket'...
2023-01-03T15:16:13.959Z [INFO]: # Checking for Git submodules at: /codebuild/output/src695397835/src/inket/.gitmodules
2023-01-03T15:16:13.967Z [INFO]: # Retrieving environment cache...
2023-01-03T15:16:14.014Z [WARNING]: ! Unable to write cache: {"code":"ERR_BAD_REQUEST","message":"Request failed with status code 404"})}
2023-01-03T15:16:14.015Z [INFO]: ---- Setting Up SSM Secrets ----
2023-01-03T15:16:14.015Z [INFO]: SSM params {"Path":"/amplify/d3exa9gu4x1ian/main/","WithDecryption":true}
2023-01-03T15:16:14.074Z [INFO]: # Defaulting to Node version 16
2023-01-03T15:16:25.232Z [INFO]: # Node version 16 is available for installation
2023-01-03T15:16:25.318Z [INFO]: # Installing Node version 16
2023-01-03T15:16:32.947Z [INFO]: # Now using Node version 16
2023-01-03T15:16:33.069Z [INFO]: No live updates for this build run
2023-01-03T15:16:33.075Z [INFO]: # Retrieving cache...
2023-01-03T15:16:33.116Z [INFO]: # Retrieved cache
2023-01-03T15:17:18.783Z [INFO]: ## Starting Backend Build
                                 ## Checking for associated backend environment...
                                 ## No backend environment association found, continuing...
                                 ## Completed Backend Build
2023-01-03T15:17:18.785Z [INFO]: {"backendDuration": 0}
                                 ## Starting Frontend Build
                                 # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: npm ci
2023-01-03T15:17:20.970Z [WARNING]: npm ERR! code
2023-01-03T15:17:20.970Z [WARNING]: ERESOLVE
2023-01-03T15:17:20.973Z [WARNING]: npm
2023-01-03T15:17:20.973Z [WARNING]: ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
                                    npm
2023-01-03T15:17:20.973Z [WARNING]: ERR!
                                    npm ERR! While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
                                    npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
                                    npm ERR!
2023-01-03T15:17:20.973Z [WARNING]: node_modules/react
                                    npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
                                    npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.10.5
                                    npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
                                    npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"^11.10.5" from the root project
                                    npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.10.5
                                    npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
                                    npm ERR!       @emotion/styled@"^11.10.5" from the root project
                                    npm
2023-01-03T15:17:20.973Z [WARNING]: ERR!       3 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system)
                                    npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system)
                                    npm ERR!   15 more (@emotion/styled, ...)
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
                                    npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
                                    npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
                                    npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
                                    npm ERR!   peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.3
                                    npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/icons
                                    npm ERR!     @material-ui/icons@"^4.11.3" from the root project
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
                                    npm
2023-01-03T15:17:20.974Z [WARNING]: ERR! node_modules/react
                                    npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
                                    npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core
                                    npm ERR!     @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
                                    npm ERR!     peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.3
                                    npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/icons
                                    npm ERR!       @material-ui/icons@"^4.11.3" from the root project
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
                                    npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
                                    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! See /root/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
2023-01-03T15:17:20.975Z [WARNING]: 
2023-01-03T15:17:20.975Z [WARNING]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
                                    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-01-03T15_17_19_007Z-debug-0.log
2023-01-03T15:17:20.980Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-01-03T15:17:20.981Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2023-01-03T15:17:20.981Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-01-03T15:17:20.981Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

I tried adding a service role, reconnecting my Github repo, and adding the Amplify.yaml file to the root directory of my repo but it didn't work.

Comment: Pull your backend and do one change at a time. Check CloudFormation to see which stack failed.